# How do I override the default design of a ordered list in html?

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have this code on my website.

```html
<ol>
  <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
  <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
  <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ol>
```

The default of this website shows for the "Ordered List" `<ol>` a dot, which is generally ok.
On this specific page I however would like to override the default design with a numeric list. I understand this would look like this:

```html
<ol type="1">
  <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
  <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
  <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ol>
```

How can I amend the code, so the default design of this website is overwritten on this specific page?
At the moment it still shows the dots verses numbers.

Comment: An ordered list with `<ol>` already shows the list items as numbers, unless you change it in your code with CSS. So, where/how do you change the default behaviour of the display of ordered lists? Please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE] which generates the wrong display for a given `<ol>` list.

Answer (score 1):

With `javascript` you can do something like that:

```js
var notNumOl = document.querySelectorAll('ol'); // find all OL elements
for (var i=0; i < notNumOl.length; i++) { 
  if (notNumOl[i].getAttribute('type') && notNumOl[i].getAttribute('type') !== '1') { // if it's not numeric
    notNumOl[i].setAttribute('type', '1'); // make it numeric
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ol>




<ol>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Progman already mentioned in his comment, an [ordered list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp) typically is a numbered list of items. That means that your css somewhere overrides the default look of the list item with the bullet-style of an [unordered list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp).

Here are three examples to illustrate what I mean.

Regular ordered & numbered list:

```html
<ol>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ol>
```

Regular unordered & bulleted list:

```html
<ul>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
    <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ul>
```

[Override](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) default list-item style for ul & ol:

```css
ol.disc {
   list-style-type: disc;
}

ul.decimal {
   list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
 <ol class="disc">
     <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
     <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
     <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
  </ol>
 
 <ul class="decimal">
     <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
     <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
     <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
 </ul>
```

There are tons of properts values for list-items as mentioned in the link above, so it's all your choice what suits your needs..

If  you need to override the disc-style for your ol (which is not default btw), you can always use *!important*:

```
<ol style="list-style-type: decimal!important;">
         <li><span style="color: #000000;">Diese Geschäftsbedingungen...</span></li>
         <li><span style="color: #000000;">Die Untervermietung...</span></li>
         <li><span style="color: #000000;">Geschäftsbedingungen des Kunden...</span></li>
</ol>
```